# Primefaces form is not updating from within dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a view like so:

```jsf
<h:form id="productForm">
  <p:messages
    id="productFormMessages"
    autoUpdate="true"
    redisplay="true"
    globalOnly="true" />

  <p:panelGrid
     id="detailsGrid">
    <p:row>
      ...
      <p:column>
        ...
        <p:outputLabel
          id="fieldToUpdateId"
          value="XYZ" />
        <p:commandButton
          action="#{bean.prepareDialog}"
          update="dialogFormId"
          oncomplete="PF('dialogModal').show();" />
      </p:column>
    </p:row>
   </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>

<ui:include src="/../.../dialog.xhtml" />
```

And this is what dialog.xhtml looks like:

```jsf
<p:dialog
  id="dialogId"
  widgetvar="dialogModal"
  appendTo="@(body)"
  modal="true"
  dynamic="true">

<h:form
  id="dialogFormId">
  ...a selectOneMenu...

  <p:commandButton
     id="saveButtonId"
     value="Save"
     actionListener="#{bean.save}"
     oncomplete="PF('dialogModal').hide();"
     process="@form"
     update=":productForm" />
  </h:form>
```

But the save button just refuses to update the productForm. It does update productFormMessages (which I'm guessing is because of the autoUpdate) but the form just doesn't update. I need to do a page reload from the browser in order for it to reflect the latest data. I have tried many different ways of doing this.
1. Using p:component to directly refer to the outputLabel in the update attribute.
2. (1) also using the form ID and the panelGrid ID.
3. Using the full client ID (with and without the preceeding ':') in the update attribute. Similarly using the form ID and the panelGrid ID.
4. Adding the client ID to the render IDs in the bean and then calling the partialViewContext#update method on that.
4. Setting partialViewContext#setRenderAll to true.
4. And as a last ditch attempt, as demonstrated by the code, updating the entire productForm. Which isn't so bad, because fieldToUpdateId is just one of the fields that I need to update in the form. But either way, it's not working.

Clearly, the data is being saved on the back end, because a page reload gives me the latest data. But I just can't get the dialog to update the form where it's being called from. I'm out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are referencing the other form correctly. Check your save method why it does not update.

Comment: But the update reference of the dialog form isn't correct. It must be `update=":dialogFormId"`.
Did you test the ids in your browser? Is 'productForm' top-level?

Comment: The save method is huge so there's not much point trying to condense it and put it here. The reason I'm updating :productForm is because on save, I am closing the dialog and displaying a 'save successful' message on productFormMessages. This is being displayed. So I'm sure that the save method has worked correctly. And yes, I did check the client IDs in the browser, productForm is the top level form.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this should work, But please inspect the button in the Html source, to make sure which part of the html it refresh. it should have something like this.

onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'dialogFormId:saveButtonId1',**u:'productForm'**,onco:function(xhr,status,args){PF('dialogModal').hide();;}});return false;"

Comment: Yes I have tried the way you have shown as well. Without the ':'. My button actually has a similar oncomplete function to what you have, I just excluded that from the code posted here for the sake of simplicity, as that can't be affecting the page refresh. All the function is doing is closing the dialog if the context validation has not failed.